# How can I create a custom task form in Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: 2010, workflow, visual-studio, asp.net, custom-form

Is there an easy way to create a custom task form with asp.net/Visual Studio for Sharepoint 2010? I worked with WSS3 before, where you can easily add the form URL to the workflow.xml file but in Sharepoint 2010 it wants an URN in the elements.xml what really drives me crazy because I don't get it to work. Most of the tutorials about custom forms I found were about creating forms with InfoPath or Designer but I can't use both of these programs. Is there a way to create forms in SP 2010 with VS2010 similar to the way it works in WSS3?

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a very helpful tutorial. So if someone else needs to work with custom asp.net task forms you should take a look at

http://www.microsofttechnology.net/2012/05/create-workflow-with-custom-task-form_7581.html.

Comment: The URL is not longer work

Answer (score 1):

Very Helpfull for maling workflow for Bigners
http://sp2013.pro/2013/03/creating-spd-2013-workflows-part-23-implementing-custom-asp-net-task-form/
Regards

Answer (score 0):

****Workflow For Bigners****
Very Helpfull for maling workflow for Bigners
http://sp2013.pro/2013/03/creating-spd-2013-workflows-part-23-implementing-custom-asp-net-task-form/
Regards
Fayyaz Ahmed Pakistan
fayyazcs@gmail.com